# Rename files in a folder to one name

Tags: shell-script, files, mv

I have multiple .pdb files in different folders. How to loop in through entire directory naming all files to one particular name test.pdb?

Sample structure

```
file1 
 file1.pdb
 xyz.txt

file2
 file2.pdb 
 xyz.txt

file3
 file3.pdb
 xyz.txt
```

Desired output structure

```
file1
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt

file2
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt

file3
 test.pdb
 xyz.txt
```

The code I am using at the moment :

```
for d in */ ; do
    mv *.pdb test.pdb
done
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a single .pdb file in each of your directories (the question doesn't make sense otherwise):

```sh
for dir in */ ; do
    [ -f "$dir/*.pdb" ] && mv "$dir/*.pdb" "$dir/test.pdb"
done
```

Comment: `-e`? really? test for regular files only with `[ -f ... ]`

Comment: I tried to make your solution look more elegant, excuse me if too much

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate reasons that your attempt isn't working:

1. You aren't using the variable `d` that you are using to iterate over the directory.
2. Your iteration glob doesn't include the final files, only the sub-directories.

EDIT: Here, first, is an improved simpler answer that doesn't require performing any checks because the initial glob selects only the pdb files.

```
for one-path in root-directory/*/*.pdb
do
  mv "$one-path" "$(dirname $one-path)/test.pdb"
done
```

My original inferior answer follows, along with some comments, using the bash shell and two core utilities (`basename` and `dirname`):

```
for one-path in root-directory/*/*
do
  [[ "$(basename "$one-path")" =~ pdb$ ]] \
  &&  mv "$one-path" "$(dirname $one-path)/test.pdb"
done
```

1. `root-directory` is whatever absolute path-spec you are using.
2. `root-directory/*/*` is a glob that will return actual files in your defined case, not just sub-directories.
3. `=~` is a bash shell extension to allow limited regular expression testing, in this case for a string ending with `pdb`
4. `&&` is a logical AND; it's a common idiom replacement for a simple `if`...`then` (don't forget the back-slash continuation symbol on the prior line).

Comment: is that Bashism `=~` avoidable, maybe..?

Comment: oh, it's some older answer, delete it from your answer! it's long